# Randomised Audio List is not playing when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, random, jplayer

***Functionality:***

Random Audio is played in gamepage for a period of 25 seconds, before audio is stopped at the 26th seconds.

***What has been done:***

I have created an array list for the audio files, a randomised method to randomised the audioList and lastly, to play the random audio.

***Issue:***

The audio is not playing and the following error msg is shown;

> Index.html:1221 Uncaught TypeError: PlaySound.play is not a function

```js
 var audioList = ["lib/audio/Awesome.mp3", "lib/audio/Excellent.mp3", "lib/audio/Fantastic.mp3", "lib/audio/Great.mp3", "lib/audio/KeepitUp.mp3", "lib/audio/MatchGame.mp3", "lib/audio/MatchSpot1.mp3", "lib/audio/MatchSpot3.mp3"];


 $('#DefaultGamePage').fadeIn({
       duration: slideDuration,
       queue: false,
       complete: function() {

         $('#DefaultGameTimer').show();

         //Play Randomised Audio
         var random_Play Audio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (audioList.length));
         var PlaySound = audioList[random_PlayAudio];
         PlaySound.play();
         ...(other game method)..
       },
       1000)
```

```html
<div id="GamePage" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:20; top:0px; left:0px; width: 1080px; height: 1920px; margin:auto;">

  <audio id="Play"></audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`audioList` is not an audio element but `array` and it do not have method `play()`

Set the `src` property of the `AudioElement` as random audion file and Use `play()` method over element having id as play.

Try this:

```js
var audioList = ["lib/audio/Awesome.mp3", "lib/audio/Excellent.mp3", "lib/audio/Fantastic.mp3", "lib/audio/Great.mp3", "lib/audio/KeepitUp.mp3", "lib/audio/MatchGame.mp3", "lib/audio/MatchSpot1.mp3", "lib/audio/MatchSpot3.mp3"];

var playElem = $('#Play').get(0); //select audio element

var handler = function() {
  var random_PlayAudio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (audioList.length));
  playElem.src = audioList[random_PlayAudio];
  playElem.addEventListener("ended", handler); //on end of the audio, execute `handler` again
  playElem.play();
};


$('#DefaultGamePage').fadeIn({
  duration: slideDuration,
  queue: false,
  complete: function() {
    $('#DefaultGameTimer').show();
    handler();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="GamePage" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:20; top:0px; left:0px; width: 1080px; height: 1920px; margin:auto;">
  <audio id="Play"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! but only one random audio is played, it did not play the entire list, should `get(0)` be edited to `.get(audioList)`??

Comment: When do you expect another audio to be played ? `OnComplete` of earlier audio ? If yes, code it accordingly..

Comment: the next audio will be played after the each earlier played audio

Comment: ok, but that will result in a type error, cause .src will be undefined

Comment: I have tested this code before posting..What error you are facing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105465/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-luke).

Comment: Index.html:885 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

Comment: Or try `var playElem = document.getElementById('Play');`

Comment: ok, I would like to ask, the current method,is for audio to play immediately after each audio. Hence, if you want an interval of say 2.5s, is this how you get it done: `var GameAudio = setInterval(function() {
                                handler();
                            },2500);`??

Comment: Does provided solution solve the question ? If yes then you should ask another question for your queries..This is how community works..